# Wrong microphone used by default

Tags: microphone

There seem to be two microphones detected by my system. The one that is selected by default doesn't work. I found an app called indicator-sound-switcher which allows me to switch to the other mic which does work but I have to do that every time I log out or reboot.

When I go to the input tab of the sound settings, it seems that the default microphone (not working) is called "Internal Microphone" and the other (working) is called "Microphone".

If I use pavucontrol, it shows both microphones. If I deselect the "set as default" button on the Internal Microphone, it is automatically reselected by the next time I switch to that microphone.

I don't have any microphone plugged in. Just the built-in one on my laptop.

I'm not sure where to start looking for clues as to how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Basically follow the way described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266025).

Determine which device it is working through. run

gstreamer-properties

And test all the ALSA mics. Find one that works. It should be something like `hw:1,1` or `hw:0,1` and so on. Than edit the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` accordingly

Comment: My problem seems to be fixed. I can't say the above fixed it but it is working. I tried editing the default.pa and played with the instructions at the link until I started getting an error saying "No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon". Once that happened, my problem stopped. I don't believe in the end I have made any changes to the default.pa.